# Avoiding switch loop

Tags: networking, switch, spanning-tree

Will I have loop problems with this topology because S2 and S3 are both connected to S1 and s4 ? 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without STP, yes you would have a loop.

Make sure that STP is enabled and configured correctly, though, and you won't need to worry about loops.

Comment: I would make sure to use at least RSTP if not MSTP.

Comment: If PC1 will send a packet to pc4, packets will transit throughout s2, S1 and s4, s3 will send them to PC4 and then S1 and S4 will delete them or ? there are a loop but PC4 will get the packet or ?

Comment: Read up on STP. One of the links that comprise the loop will be shut down. Meaning the switch on the "far" side of the link that is disabled will never see this packet.

Comment: yes I know but I mean without STP I think there are no loops ...

Comment: You can think whatever you want, but you would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Everything will be perfectly fine as long as STP is ENABLED.
STP Will protect You against physical loop.

Looking at Your picture - however - what else is connected to S1 and S4 ? If nothing why not remove them ? STP will disable one of the links - lets assume S2-S4. So You will go around from PC1-S2-S1-S3-S4-somehting (If "something" is there).

You probably don't have a loop problem but You may have a optimal path problem.

reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol

> "The Spanning Tree Protocol (STP) is a network protocol that ensures a
>   loop-free topology"